# how to stop postback or submit event for jQuery Unobtrusive validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I am using jQuery Unobtrusive Validation and want to do few things before I submit the form.
I dont want to postback the form after successful validation, but instead want to show a success message to user and reset the same form for adding another data.

in the following code, it shows me alert only when form is not valid, if its valid it just do a postback.

Currently my form gets submitted even though I want to avoid postback in this scenario.

```
@model MyProject.ViewModels.CustomerViewModel

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#addCustomer").click(function () {

        $("#myForm").validate();

        if ($("#myForm").valid()) {

            // This part doesn't get triggered

            alert('yes valid');
            //$.post(...post my data using ajax..)
            alert('data posted successfully.');
            //clear form to submit another data
            clearForm();
            return false;
        }
        else{
            alert('no not valid');
            return false;
        }

  <form id="myForm">
    <div class="formPanel">
            <label>Display Name</label>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustomerName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerName)
    </div>
   <button class="btn btn-primary" id="addCustomer">Save</button>
  </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: I checked this article talking about simmilar issue and was really helpful. http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/539167/Modify-jQuery-validation-settings-using-MVC-unobtr

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, the `submit` event is always blocked by jQuery Validate on an invalid form.  If that's not happening, then you're not using the plugin properly.

---

You misunderstand the `.validate()` method...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#addCustomer").click(function () {

        $("#myForm").validate();

        if ($("#myForm").valid()) {
        ....
```

The `.validate()` method is only used for *initializing* the plugin on your form and never gets called within a `click` handler.  It gets called once within the DOM ready event handler and by default the click of a `type="submit"` element is automatically captured by the plugin.

Use the `submitHandler` callback function to do stuff when the form is valid.  [As per docs, this is *the proper place* to do your `ajax()`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#submithandler).  Without using the `submitHandler`, the form is submitted as a regular form and the page would redirect or reload.  Using the `submitHandler` as outlined below will prevent all that.

```
$(document).ready(function () {  // DOM ready

    $("#myForm").validate({  // initialize the plugin
        submitHandler: function(form) {  // fires on valid form
            alert('yes valid');
            //$.post(...post my data using ajax..)
            alert('data posted successfully.');
            //clear form to submit another data
            clearForm();  // <- I don't see this function in your OP
            return false;
        }
    });  

});
```

In your case, since you have a `type="button"`, you need to manually capture the click and then trigger a submit.

```
    $("#addCustomer").click(function () {  // capture click

        $("#myForm").submit(); // trigger validation test & submit
        ....
```

Otherwise, you should eliminate this `click` handler entirely by changing your button into a `type="submit"`.

```
<input type="submit" ...
```

OR

```
<button type="submit" ...
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/526Yc/**

---

**EDIT**:

The `unobtrusive-validation.js` plugin included with ASP constructs and calls the `.validate()` method automatically.  Since the jQuery Validate plugin will ignore all calls to `.validate()` after it's called once, you cannot call the `.validate()` method while also using the `unobtrusive-validation.js` plugin.  And since the OP wanted to have more control over jQuery Validation, he opted to remove the `unobtrusive-validation` plugin and construct the call to the `.validate()` method himself.

Comment: tried your code, I get alert only when its not valid but when i have valid field it submits it without showing me the alert. I tied this             if ($("#myForm").valid()) {
                alert('yes valid');
                return false;
            }
            else {
                alert('no not valid');
                return false;
            }

Comment: @rajcool111, of course it submits without showing the alert.  If the form is valid, the page redirects as per the URL in the `form` `action` attribute.  That is exactly what is supposed to happen.

Comment: Thats what my question is based on. I have some prerequisites before I submit. For example, show confirmation message before it submits OR post the valid data to my service thru ajax. Which I am unable to do.

Comment: @rajcool111, that's what the `submitHandler` is for.  To do stuff when the form is valid and before it submits.  In that case, you should use a real submit button (`type="submit"`) and eliminate the `click` handler entirely.

Comment: Thanks @Sparky...I think the approach you gave is the best solution. I was debugging jquery.validate.js and found that value for validator.settings.submitHandler is coming as "undefined". May be something is wrong in my JS framework. I have some other validation js like jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js and jquery.validate-vsdoc.js. Hope thats not causing this issue.

Comment: @rajcool111, it's possible that your `unobtrusive` validation plugin is screwing up the jQuery Validation plugin.  Since you're defining everything in jQuery, there's no point in having the `unobtrusive` plugin.

Comment: @rajcool111, you can also trying putting the `submitHandler` inside of the `setDefaults()` method.  Although, my vote would be to get rid of the `unobtrusive` plugin.  See: http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.setDefaults/

Comment: @rajcool111, I am not familiar with `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` or `jquery.validate-vsdoc.js`, but AFAIK, you shouldn't need them.